# Nuget.build package needs re-installing if you delete packages

Tags: silverlight, nuget

We use async in Silverlight which requires the NuGet.Build.2.8.6 package to be installed.

```
Install-Package NuGet.Build
```

We don't check packages into source control obviously, but installing NuGet.Build doesn't install a project level package, it... I don't know what it does, it seems to put them in "packages" but beyond that nothing changes. However, if you don't you get this error:

> Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1

What changes is this package actually making to the system that are impossible to "check in" to source control?

Is there a fix so I don't have to install package every time I get a clean copy?

Comment: That error message seems unrelated to me since NuGet.Build does not depend on Microsoft.Bcl. You normally get that error when you are installing the Microsoft.Bcl NuGet package with an older version of the NuGet package manager. NuGet.Build is a solution level package and it will be added to the .nuget\packages.config file inside the solution directory. This file will need to be checked in so the oackage restore works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message seems unrelated to me since NuGet.Build does not depend on Microsoft.Bcl. You normally get that error when you are installing the Microsoft.Bcl NuGet package with an older version of the NuGet package manager.

NuGet.Build is a solution level package and it will be added to a `.nuget\packages.config` file inside the solution directory. This file will need to be checked in so the package restore works.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's specifically because we are using the bcl library. That solves the problem actually it seems the .nuget\packages.config is not being updated. My suspicion is it's locked somehow and failing silently to update... I can work around that. Great work thanks.